# How can I get an HTML element to remove from the regular document flow and be relatively positioned?

Tags: html, css, image

Other than position:absolute, and float: what other ways are there to remove an element from the regular document flow?

If you must have some code, it is very basic.
This would be a looping result of a foreach loop in php.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p>Maybe some words are here<p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Some text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <img class="favoritesbutton" src="./images/emptystar.png" />
</div>
```

I want `.favoritesbutton` to be out of the regular document flow.

Comment: can you show us some code? You should add `position:relative;` to the parent of the absolute positioned element, and stick with the absolute positioning, but hard to tell exactly without seeing any code

Comment: The specific code here is really not relevant at all.  All it would serve to do is clutter the question.  I will rephrase my question.

Comment: when you have an issue with your code, the code is obviously relevant. It does not need to be your actual code, just a snippet that reproduces the issue will do. And btw, float does not remove an element from the flow! I do believe it is `position: absolute` you are after, bat as i said, hard to tell without seeing the code...

Comment: Okay, I wrote a mock up of the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need 'position:absolute;' to achieve this.

Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zfUxP/

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.favoritesbutton {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

The key lays in setting the wrapper to `position: relative` to serve as a reference for the absolute positioning of the child favoritesbutton

Comment: Thank you. It also seems important to note that this does exactly what I need done, but if one were to leave out the left: and top: values, it breaks and acts like a normal relatively positioned element.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you might try adding `position:relative` to each "container element" and `position: absolute` plus some positioning (`left`, `right` etc) for the favourite icon.

I'd advice you to add a drawing or something of what you're trying to achieve though.

Comment: I just realized that this answer is actually correct, but at first, I did not notice because I was unaware of the necessity of adding left:0; top:0; to the absolutely positioned "child" to make it work, and when I tried it, it did not help.  Just tossing some credit where it's due.

Comment: Ah. The positioning properties (left, right, top, bottom) won't work without using `position: absolute|relative|fixed`, and `position:absolute` will position itself absolutely according to the nearest parent element with position relative, absolute or fixed. See details at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme

Comment: The problem wasn't that I didn't think the positioning properties (left, right, top, bottom) weren't working, it was that I thought the position: was not working right.  The lack of those, not position: was the problem.  Thank you for your help!